# The animation video_player flutter is not displayed

Tags: android, flutter, dart, animation, flutter-video-player

When I am running current code... I get this error:

```
UnimplementedError (UnimplementedError: init() has not been implemented.)
```

*In phone all very slowdown show on display, but errors not found!*

**Code**:

```dart
final videos = [
  'assets/videos/Frozen_Flower_In_Ice_1402.mp4',
  'assets/videos/Main_EarthPlanet.mp4',
];

class VideosScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideosScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<VideosScreen> createState() => _VideosScreenState();
}

class _VideosScreenState extends State<VideosScreen> {
  late PageController _pageController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView.builder(
      controller: _pageController,
      itemCount: videos.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return VideoCard(
          assetPath: videos[index],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class VideoCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoCard({
    super.key,
    required this.assetPath,
  });

  final String assetPath;

  @override
  State<VideoCard> createState() => _VideoCardState();
}

class _VideoCardState extends State<VideoCard> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset(widget.assetPath);

    _controller
      ..addListener(() => setState(() {}))
      ..setLooping(true)
      ..setVolume(0)
      ..initialize().then((_) => setState(() {}))
      ..play();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 32, horizontal: 16),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
            offset: const Offset(0, 6),
            blurRadius: 8,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
          child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In videos errors not!

And more... when I start app in chrome... app not slowdown show on display as in the phone although ram memory in excess.

Set duration and rewrote code and lower fps... nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

*The problem was that for some reason the player does not work on windows.*
And if we talk about the phone, I can safely say! 4k images at 240 fps are not the best idea to put on the phone) I think I helped those who also faced such a problem.

I recommend putting pictures no more than 60 seconds and no more than 60 fps.

good luck to everyone)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).